# Yii max column size

Tags: yii

How can I get the max length/size of a table column by using a function?
For example, if I'm trying to get the size of a VARCHAR(25) column, I would like to obtain the value "25" in the code for that specific attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$row = SomeModel::model()->find();
var_dump($row->getMetaData()->columns['someCol']->size);
```